# Разрешить и не минусовать, если ответ на вопрос написан на английском, а не на русском языке

Tags: обсуждение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Stackoverflow на русском* - предназначен для русскоговорящих программистов.

Мы знаем, что русскоговорящие живут не только в странах бывшего СССР, но и в Америке, Германии, Англии и т.д. Те, кто давно переехал в такие страны, покупают местную технику, которая может не поддерживать русский язык (пример: клавиатура **только амер/англ раскладки**).

***Проблема:***

Мне удобнее читать и вникать в информацию на русском, чем на английском. Но помимо того, что читать материал, я хочу помогать другим находить ответы на интересующие задающего вопросы. Недавно я дал свой ответ на английском языке, потому что компьютер был (на тот момент) **только с английской раскладкой клавиатуры** и возможности писать по-русски - не было. Люди с рейтингом выше 2500-7000 начали писать, чтобы я сделал перевод объяснения программы.

Хотелось бы перед задачей интересующих меня вопросов отметить, что программист должен знать английский язык.

1. в высокоуровневых языках программирования используется для обозначений типов данных, методов, классов и т.д. английские слова.
2. английский язык - это международный язык общения.

***Вопросы:***

1. Можно ли отвечать на английском, если нет возможности написать на английском?
   *(P.S. предлагали перевод в google translate, но представьте, что это не 5 слов, а 5 параграфов текста как в данном моем вопросе)*
2. Если нету возможности ответить на вопрос на русском, но ты знаешь ответ, что делать тогда в моем случае?
   (P.S. игнорирование не всегда есть хорошо. В среднем на вопрос отвечает 0-4 человека и ответ не всегда вовремя "приходит" от участников сообщества или же ответ может не отвечать на вопрос задающего.)

Comment: "программист не просто должен, а обязан знать английский язык" Не начинайте...

Comment: @Suvitruf исправил

Comment: У ресурса есть правила, вы их нарушаете, чего вы ждете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я этого не видел в справке

Comment: Вон @VladD транслитерирует и не жалуется..

Comment: у меня клавиатура вообще без букв :)

Comment: Есть (по крайней мере была популярна когда-то у пользователей эмбарговских компов) такая раскладка -- QWERTY (ЯВЕРТЫ). Как раз для вашего случая

Answer (score 10):

Проблема в том что вас таких мало. Одно время мы даже самостоятельно переводили английские вопросы - пока не пошли жалобы на то, что с таким трудом заданный на английском вопрос оказался переведен на русский каким-то вандалом. Так что нет, правила меняться точно не будут.

Что же можно сделать в такой ситуации? Тут есть несколько вариантов.

**Во-первых, можно просто запомнить где какая клавиша находится.** Раз уж вы начали выкладывать фотографии клавиатур - держите мою:

[image]

Как видно, часть клавиш стерлась - но мне это нисколько не мешает.

Только не надо думать что для этого нужна эйдетическая память или долгое зубрение: расположение клавиш на клавиатуре гораздо проще запоминается в моторной памяти ("руки помнят"). На начальной стадии обучения можно использовать экранную клавиатуру в качестве подсказки.

**Во-вторых, гугл понимает транслит.** Можно просто написать сообщение транслитом в поиске гугла и он его расшифрует:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В третьих**, мы же программисты! Можно написать юзерскрипт или браузерное расширение, которые будут декодировать транслит.

**В четвертых**, существуют наклейки на клавиатуру, с помощью которых на любую клавиатуру можно добавить русскую раскладку. В конце концов, можно купить клавиатуру с русской раскладкой...

Comment: Мне было физически неуютно на эту клавиатуру смотреть )=

Comment: @Suvitruf "было"? :-)

Comment: Не, до такого не доводил, к счастью :D

Comment: @Suvitruf, ага, её стоило бы почистить или хотя бы продуть.

Comment: У вас в шифте образовалось углубление? Такого я ещё не видел :) у меня максимум на старой клавиатуре кнопки пополам разламывались.

Comment: @АндрейNOP вы еще левого контрола не видели, он в кадр не попал. Там по центру углубления - дырка :-) (радиус где-то миллиметр,  палец ее не замечает)

Comment: Суровая челябинская клавиатура

Answer (score 9):

> Мне удобнее читать и вникать в информацию на русском, чем на английском.

Тем, кто будет читать твой ответ - тоже.

Почему если тебе удобнее писать на английском, кто-то другой должен быть вынужден читать и вникать на английском при том, что вы оба на русском сайте?

> потому что компьютер был (на тот момент) только с английской раскладкой клавиатуры и возможности писать по-русски - не было

Наклейки на клавиатуру стоят меньше доллара.

[image: наклейки на клавиатуру 1]

[image: наклейки на клавиатуру 2]

Answer (score 5):

> Мы знаем, что русскоговорящие живут не только в странах бывшего СССР,
>   но и в Америке, Германии, Англии и т.д. Те, кто давно переехал в такие
>   страны, покупают местную технику, которая может не поддерживать
>   русский язык

У меня ноут куплен в Эмиратах. Там нету русской раскладки, но я пишу на русском. Что я делаю не так? Поддержка языков на уровне софта настраивается, а не на уровне железа.

> программист не просто должен, а обязан знать английский язык

Вообще, нет. Но это старый спор. Рекомендуется, но не должен.

> Можно ли отвечать на английском, если нет возможности написать на
>   английском? (P.S. предлагали перевод в google translate, но
>   представьте, что это не 5 слов, а 5 параграфов текста как в данном
>   моем вопросе)

Google translate вполне неплохо переваривает цельные тексты.

Comment: _У меня ноут куплен в Эмиратах._ - оу, выпендриваться будем? :)

Comment: @Grundy да нет, просто, так сказать, по собственному опыту сужу.

Comment: _Google translate вполне неплохо переваривает цельные тексты._ - можно добавить, что переведенный текст вполне могут поправить, в отличие от

Comment: + в случае острого желания ответить можно воспользоваться виртуальной клавиатурой

Comment: Если русской раскладки совсем нет, можно использовать сервисы типа translit.ru

Comment: @VladD, либо просто установить русскую раскладку